# Strange function definition result

Tags: function-construction, project-euler

I'm relatively new to Mathematica, and I'm trying to define a function f(k) that would do the following:

> For any positive integer $k$, a finite sequence $a_i$ of fractions $\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ is defined by: 
>   $$a_1 = \frac{1}{k}\\
> a_i = \frac{x_{i-1}+1}{y_{i-1}-1}$$
>   When $a_i$ reaches some integer $n$, the sequence stops.
>   (That is, when $y_i=1$.) Define $f(k) = n$.

-- [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=343)

I have the following function written:

```
f[k_, sofar_] = Module[{num, result},
  result =
   If[sofar == 0,1/k,((num = Numerator[sofar]) + 1)/(num/sofar - 1)
    ];
  If[IntegerQ[result],result,f[k,result]]
 ];
f[k_] = f[k, 0]
```

But I get the result `{ComplexInfinity,List}` and I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function needs to depend on *both* $x_{i-1}$ and $y_{i-1}$.  (This answer applies to any programming language you might choose for tackling this problem.)

Comment: I rephrased the format of the question from Project Euler. The fraction is reduced before the function is re-applied.

Comment: Yep, but you still need to track the numerator and denominator, so you might as well do so explicitly--at least conceptually.  Your life will be *much* easier.  (*Mathematica* can handle many of the details, but under the hood it will be doing exactly the same thing: carrying an ordered pair of (numerator, denominator) around.)

Comment: so I pass $x_i/y_i$ as $sofar$ and then determine the new numerator, then $\frac{num}{sofar}$ is $y_i$

Comment: @whuber After completely changing my code such that it works in the way you suggested, the problem goes away. Huh. Thanks.

Comment: Just to get you started: `f[q_] := (Numerator[q] + 1) / (Denominator[q] - 1)` takes care of the basic iteration step.  Read the manual page for `NestWhile` to find out how to stop the iteration.  Generate an initial sequence of results and then look it up in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) for an *excellent* additional hint (including more *Mathematica* code).

Comment: Mine's a bit more cumbersome, but all in one function: `f[num_, denom_] =
 If[Mod[num, denom] == 0, num, 
  f[(num + 1)/GCD[num + 1, denom - 1], (denom - 1)/
    GCD[num + 1, denom - 1]]]
f[x1_] = f[1, x1]`

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to solve your problem?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat Here's a perhaps more "Mathematica-idiomatic" form: `next[{n_, d_} /; Divisible[n, d]] := n/d; next[{n_, d_}] := Module[{a = (n + 1)/(d - 1)}, {Numerator[a], Denominator[a]}];f[k_] := NestWhile[next, {1, k}, ListQ];` And here's what you might consider the ideal: `f[n_] := n; f[Rational[n_, d_]] := f[(n + 1)/(d - 1)];` usage: `f[1/n]`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to use `:=` instead of `=` with the function definition so that it is not evaluated immediately.